# DataStax DevCenter cannot create new connection in Windows

Tags: cassandra

When I am trying to test a new connection it returns an error:

The specified host(s) could not be reached.
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /host_ip:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/host_ip:9042] Cannot connect))
  [/host_ip:9042] Cannot connect

In my windows firewall, I have already created a rule for DevCenter, which allows DevCenter to communicate with remote Cassandra server. I have no access to Cassandra server but it is configured well, it means that the problem is somewhere on my local computer.

Comment: Can you try with DBever for same?

Comment: What is your listen_address & rpc_address in cassandra.yaml?

Comment: Are you able to connect using `cqlsh` from the machine you have DevCenter installed? You can access `cqlsh` from the bin folder of cassandra distribution.

Comment: Problem is solved, it was server configuration problems.

Comment: Do you still remember what the reason was for the error?

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing typically happens when the host crashes expectantly resulting in the corruption of the sstables or commitlog files.

This is why it is really important to use replication since when you get into this situation you can run `nodetool repair` to repair the corrupted tables and data from other nodes.

If you are not fortunate enough to have replication configured, then you are in for some data loss. Clear the suspect file from `\data\commitlogs`, cry a little and restart the node.